# jQuery if a checkbox is checked, disable other specific checkboxes based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Here what I need is,

```
<div id="employeedetails-relation" class="check"><div class="checkbox">    <label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="1"> Father</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="2"> Mother</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="3"> Spouse</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="4"> Child1</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="5"> Child2</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="6"> Father-in-law</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="7"> Mother-in-law</label></div></div>
```

Here if I check value **1** *or* **2**, then value **6** *and* **7** checkbox must get disabled. And the same way if I check value **6** *or* **7**, then checkbox value **1** *and* **2** must get disabled.

Suppose if I check value 3 first and then if I checked value 1 or 2, again value 6 and 7 must be get disabled.

If I unchecked value 1 and checked value 2, again value 6 and 7 must be get disabled, alternatively

My code:

```
$(\'input[type="checkbox"]\').click(function(){

        if (this.checked && this.value === "1") {
        $(\'#employeedetails-relation input[value="6"\').prop(\'disabled\', \'true\');
        $(\'#employeedetails-relation input[value="7"\').prop(\'disabled\', \'true\');
        } 
        elseif (!this.checked && this.value === "1")
        {
        $(\'#employeedetails-relation input[value="6"\').prop(\'disabled\', \'false\');
        $(\'#employeedetails-relation input[value="7"\').prop(\'disabled\', \'false\');
        }
```

Comment: show us the code you have tried

Comment: see above i have updated my question

Comment: i tried this, its working, but  if checked both value 1 and 2, then value 6 and 7 getting diasble, suppose if i unchecked any value  from 1 or 2 then value 6 and 7 getting enable

Comment: why do you escape the ' in your code? to select all the checkbox elements $('input[type="checkbox"]') should to the job.

Comment: I think you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have different click handlers for the set 1,2 or 6,7 then check whether any of those are checked and then set the disabled property

```js
var $checks12 = $('#employeedetails-relation').find('input[value="1"], input[value="2"]').click(function() {
  $checks67.prop('disabled', $checks12.is(':checked'));
});
var $checks67 = $('#employeedetails-relation').find('input[value="6"], input[value="7"]').click(function() {
  $checks12.prop('disabled', $checks67.is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="employeedetails-relation" class="check">
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="1"/> Father</label></div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="2"/> Mother</label></div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="3"/> Spouse</label></div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="4"/> Child1</label></div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="5"/> Child2</label></div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="6"/> Father-in-law</label></div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="7"/> Mother-in-law</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this code exactly working in jsfiiddle but the problem is not working in yii2. I mean if i check father or mother, fatherinlaw and motherinlaw  getting disable. while father or mother is checked and if i check spouse suddenly fatherinlaw and motherinlaw checkbox not getting disable

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#employeedetails-relation').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());

        var checkedEl = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            checkedEl.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
        });

        $('#employeedetails-relation :checkbox').prop('disabled', false);

        if ($.inArray(1, checkedEl) > -1 || $.inArray(2, checkedEl) > -1) {
            $(':checkbox[value=6]').prop('disabled', true);
            $(':checkbox[value=7]').prop('disabled', true);
        } else if ($.inArray(6, checkedEl) > -1 || $.inArray(7, checkedEl) > -1) {

            $(':checkbox[value=1]').prop('disabled', true);
            $(':checkbox[value=2]').prop('disabled', true);
        }

    });
});
```

Check Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0hoh109k/1/

Comment: this code exactly working in jsfiiddle but the problem is not working in yii2. here if i check father, fatherinlaw and motherinlaw not getting disable. same for all other checkbox i dont know why

Comment: @KalaiS That means you're missing something

Comment: the code given by you, i have pasted there according to yii2, i didn't miss anything

Comment: @KalaiS You need to update the conditions according to your requirements, and add new conditions if required

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple errors in your javascript code. remove the backslash in your jquery selectors as follows:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

you also forgot the end brackets in your selectors:

```
$('#employeedetails-relation input[value="6"]')
```

elseif does not exist in javascript, replace it with:

```
else if
```

here you can find a workin example of your code http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/up59vsdg/1/.

Answer (score 0):

The Perfect and Tested solution ...Just copy and paste and check

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      if($(this).val()==1 || $(this).val()==2 ){
      $('#checkbox6').attr('disabled','true');    
       $('#checkbox7').attr('disabled','true');    
      }
      })  
    // var check= document.getElementsByName('Employeedetails[relation][]');

   //  alert(check.val);
    });
    </script>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
        <div id="employeedetails-relation" class="check"><div class="checkbox">    <label><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="1"> Father</label></div>

<div class="checkbox"><label><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="2"> Mother</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="3"> Spouse</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="4"> Child1</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input  id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="5"> Child2</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input   id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="6"> Father-in-law</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input id="checkbox7"  type="checkbox" name="Employeedetails[relation][]" value="7"> Mother-in-law</label></div>   </div>
      </body>
</html>
```